# How do I store/retrieve a List of DocumentSnapshot from Firestore in offline mode?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a book app and the app doesn't have authentication but I wanted to save a list of favorite books of the user in form of List to retrieve it i my favorite screen and show each DocumentSnapshot on my Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing special to do. If you've enabled firestore persistence (which is on by default for ios and android) then the first time you execute a query - firestore will fetch it from the server. Next time when you execute the same query if in offline mode - firestore will serve you the results from cache.